# Getting started with Python OCR on windows?

Tags: python, python-imaging-library, anaconda, python-tesseract, pytesser

I have never used python before, and I am not sure where to start. My goal is to take image data, of numbers and multicolored background, and reliably get the correct characters identified. I looked into the tools necessary for this and I found the Anaconda python distribution which included all the possible packages I might need for this, as well as tesseract-ocr and pytesser.

Unfortunately, I'm lost in how to begin. I"m using the PyCharm Community IDE and simply trying to follow this guide:
http://www.manejandodatos.es/2014/11/ocr-python-easy/
to get a grasp on OCR.

This is the code I'm using:

```
from PIL import Image
from pytesser import *

image_file = 'menu.jpg'
im = Image.open(image_file)
text = image_to_string(im)
text = image_file_to_string(image_file)
text = image_file_to_string(image_file, graceful_errors=True)
print "=====output=======\n"
print text
```

and I believe the Anaconda distribution that I'm using has PIL, but I'm getting this error:

```
C:\Users\diego_000\Anaconda\python.exe C:/Users/diego_000/PycharmProjects/untitled/test.py
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:/Users/diego_000/PycharmProjects/untitled/test.py", line 2, in <module>
    from pytesser import *
  File "C:\Users\diego_000\PycharmProjects\untitled\pytesser.py", line 6, in <module>
    import Image
ImportError: No module named Image

Process finished with exit code 1
```

Can anyone point me in the right direction?

Comment: Install Pillow. Use `from PIL import Image`

Comment: can you explain this a bit more? I already have that line written, so would I just install Pillow? Or would I delete the following line `from pytesser import *`?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The document you point to says to use

```
from PIL import Image
```

except you use

```
import Image
```

and so the interpreter properly says:

```
ImportError: No module named Image
```

It looks as if you reordered the lines

```
from PIL import Image
from pytesser import *
```

and that pytesser has a improperly coded dependency on PIL. but I can't be certain with the code you provided.

Comment: I replaced the line `import image` in pytesser.py with `from PIL import Image` and my code compiles, but I do not get any output, this must mean that the code is flawed in some way? I did replace the original .tiff image with a jpg form of it, would you happen to know if that could affect it at all?

Comment: It could very well effect it. TIFF is an uncompressed file and will have cleaner letter edges than a compress JPG.

Comment: Everything works fine when using pytesser's included fonts_test.png file, but there is a problem whenever I use any other image. I imagine it's just a limitation of pytesser then?